# On click, toggle a previously clicked icon back to it's original state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

I have two drop down menus on a navigation bar, and have gotten the icons to toggle as long as that anchor is clicked, but i can not figure out how to get one to reset if a separate sub menu is clicked. I'm asking if there's a way to make this happen with how it is laid out now, and if not, how do i achieve this?

I'm also sorry in advance if this whole thing is littered with rookie mistakes.

I tried to condense the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80wne34L/34/) as much as possible, but you may need to expand the side part to see the affected icons to the right. I left out the responsive portion.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active')
  })
  $('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  })
})
$("nav ul li a").click(function() {
  $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  background: url(img/sunset.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-icons {
  color: white;
}

header nav ul li a.active span {
  color: red;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  color: fff;
}

header nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

header nav ul li.active ul {
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li ul li a {
  background: linear-gradient(#000000, #34282C);
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: #000;
}


/*full screen header*/

header nav ul li a {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  transition: .25s;
  font-weight: ;
  color: #000000;
  background: #2196f3;
}

header nav ul li a.active {
  background: #25383C;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
}

header nav ul li a.active:before {
  content: '\f096';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="header-icons"><i class="fas fa-pen-square fa-fw"></i></span>Services<span class="sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-angle-down fa-fw"></i></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="header-icons"><i class="far fa-image fa-fw"></i></span>Portfolio<span class="sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-angle-down fa-fw"></i></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: One other option? Use CSS. What you're looking to do can be applied with pseudo classes (::focus) and sibling selectors (+). Here's an example with no JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/ejzn60rk/

Comment: This seems very useful. I like the aspect of not having to click the anchor to retract the menu. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally this is achieved by:

1. Make all arrows down.
2. Make clicked arrow up.

This function will work for you:

```
  $("nav ul li a").click(function() {
    // Cache variables (for speed)
    var $this = $(this),
        $arrow = $this.find('.sub-menu i');

    // Make all arrows point down, excepted clicked arrow
    $('.sub-menu i').not($arrow).addClass('fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-up');

    // Toggle this arrow
    $arrow.toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
    $('nav').toggleClass('active')
  })
  $('ul li').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
  // Move into $(document).ready() for good practices
  $("nav ul li a").click(function() {
    // Cache variables (for speed)
    var $this = $(this),
        $arrow = $this.find('.sub-menu i');

    // Make all arrows point down, excepted clicked arrow
    $('.sub-menu i').not($arrow).addClass('fa-angle-down').removeClass('fa-angle-up');
    
    // Toggle this arrow
    $arrow.toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  background: url(img/sunset.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #000000;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-icons {
  color: white;
}

header nav ul li a.active span {
  color: red;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
}

header nav ul li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-menu {
  color: fff;
}

header nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}

header nav ul li.active ul {
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li ul li {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

header nav ul li ul li a {
  background: linear-gradient(#000000, #34282C);
  border-style: inset;
  border-color: #000;
}


/*full screen header*/

header nav ul li a {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

header nav ul li a:hover {
  transition: .25s;
  font-weight: ;
  color: #000000;
  background: #2196f3;
}

header nav ul li a.active {
  background: #25383C;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
}

header nav ul li a.active:before {
  content: '\f096';
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  font-size: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  line-height: 50px;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-toggle {
  color: #fff;
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Practice</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="header-icons"><i class="fas fa-pen-square fa-fw"></i></span>Services<span class="sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-angle-down fa-fw"></i></span></a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="header-icons"><i class="far fa-image fa-fw"></i></span> Portfolio
            <span class="sub-menu"><i class="fas fa-angle-down fa-fw"></i></span>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link </a></li>
          </ul>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know there have been other, similar posts, but seeing it implemented into my project makes it a million times easier to learn.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution just for your reference. I check for the active class under li tag, then remove or add the fa-angle-down or fa-angle-up class on i tag.

```
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function(){
      $('nav').toggleClass('active')
  })
  $('ul li').click(function(){
      $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
      $(this).toggleClass('active');

      // Check for active class
      if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-angle-up").addClass("fa-angle-down");        
      } 
      $(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-angle-down fa-angle-up");
  })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80wne34L/79/

Comment: Interesting. This is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. If you are happy with the solution. You can mark Chris' answer as your primary solution or answer. So people will know this question is done.

Comment: Nice @DaleNguyen! I should have as well. but... ;)